# Docker-Mongodb - How to connect to the mongo image in Windows 10 local

Tags: docker, mongodb

I am trying to connect to docker mongo image in my local windows machine, I installed mongodb in local, and added the mongodb bin path to windows path environment variable. And I am doing below steps

```
cd <docker-location>

docker login

docker ps
```

> -- to check already mongo running

```
docker pull myrepo/mymongo-image:1.0
docker run -p 27017:27017 -d --net=host --name=mytestDB myrepo/mymongo-image:1.0

docker logs mytestDB
```

Output: MongoDB starting : pid=6 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=moby
    docker ps
Output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
34598734598        myrepo/mymongo-image:1.0   "/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/"   12 hours ago        Up About a minute                       mytestDB
```

start mongo in local:

```
mongo --port 27017
```

But I am getting error like this:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.1
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/test
2016-10-13T20:04:12.273+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
2016-10-13T20:04:12.277+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:226:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

Please let me know where I did mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `--net=host`. It looks like you are asking docker to publish the port since you have supplied the `-p 27017:27017` option, but `--net=host` asks Docker to turn off all network isolation features, including port publishing.

Docker-for-windows sets up a little VM in hyperv where Docker runs. Your `--net=host` container ends up listening on that VM's interfaces. The Docker-for-windows network port forwarding pays attention only to published ports, so that's why no forwarding is happening.

If your run that same command without `--net=host`, you should get a different result.

Sometimes, if you try to run a containerized process and the published port doesn't seem to be working, it is because the process is listening on the container's `lo0` interface and not the `eth0` interface.

Here's a good benchmark test container to run to test out publishing ports:

```
docker run --name testweb -d -p 8989:80 nginx:alpine
```

You should then be able to connect to http://127.0.0.1:8989 and see an nginx welcome page.